# ERD Diagram for feedback system

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, erd

I have to create an ERD Diagram based on some high level descriptions given below:

1. The recipient can pick 5 to 10 submitters in their organization to request feedback from about the recipient.
2. Feedback entered by the submitter consists of answering a number of questions about the recipient.
3. Each organization may choose from a list of pre existing questions or create their own questions.
4. The submitter can choose to be anonymous on their feedback.
5. The date of the feedback submission should be recorded and displayed to the recipient.
6. The recipient can view the contents of the feedback – including date, feedback, and submitter(if not anonymous).
7. The recipient can view a list of all feedback submitted to them, including average score across all submitters.
8. The recipient can request the above to happen multiple times (for example: in the beginning of the year and in the middle of the year)
   and average score need to be shown per time period and not across
   all answers.

This is what I drew up, I'm not sure if it's accurate. If anyone can double check and point out corrections, that would be appreciated:

Edit:

Changed the diagram to the one below. I still am not sure about the composite or foreign keys. If anyone can help me out with that?

Second Edit:
Changed the format and tried to address the issues mentioned. Changed the features a bit as well.
[image: feedbackerd[1]]

- A recipient creates a feedback
- A feedback form has access to a pre
  populated questions bank
- Feedback is assigned to submittors
- Submitter completes feedback, can choose to be anonymous
- Each submitter gets an average score for their individual feedback
- Recipient sees individual scores, as well as average of all users
- Additional comments can be added to feedback by submitter

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best answer to give you is to question potential problems so that you can think about those points:

- The diagram says that a `Feedback Question` can be about / belong to more than one `Recipient`.  Shouldn't each `Feedback Question` be about / belong to a single `Recipient`?
- How are you handling point 3 in your model?
- `Submitters` appear to be employers based on the attributes you gave them, but from the description it sounds like they're employees?
- How are you handling point 4 in your model?
- Why do `Submitters` have a `Due Date`?  How will this work with point 8?
- How will `Recipients` know to what `Feedback Question` each `Feedback Result` is related?
- The diagram says that each `Feedback Result` can be associated with multiple `Submitters`.  Don't you think there should be a separate `Feedback Result` for each `Submitter`, i.e. that each `Feedback Result` should be associated with only one `Submitter`?
- Why do `Feedback Results` have a due date?  I see only mention of a submission date in the description.
- Why record `Average Score` for each `Feedback Result`?  Wouldn't it be better to calculate it with a query?
- Why model a `Views` relationship between `Recipients` and `Feedback Results`?  Don't you think the description just calls for them to be able to view (query) the results, rather than recording their views?

In response to your edit:

- You connected `Feedback Question` directly to `Questions` without a relationship - this is not valid in ER.
- You changed `Submitters` `Due Date` to `Submission Date`, but isn't it possible for a `Submitter` to submit answers on different dates (see point 8)? I would just put a `Submission Date` on `Feedback Results` instead of the `Due Date`, and not have any date at all on `Submitters`.
- Could a `Submitter` submit some `Feedback Results` anonymously and others openly?
- You added a `Feedback ID` attribute to `Feedback Results` - I believe this should be a relationship instead.
- My suggestion for `Views` (both of them) and `Average` is not to model them at all.  Averages are derived facts - we only need to record ground facts in a database.  Viewing of data is run-time behaviour, not information that needs to be recorded.
- You say you're still not sure about the composite or foreign keys.  I can help, if you'll explain what you're unsure about.  Personally, I prefer using 1, M and N as cardinality indicators rather than crow's foot, but I can read it either way.
- I agree with your changes to the cardinalities of `Recipient`'s relationships, but I think you need to do the same with `Submits` - each `Feedback Result` should be submitted by a single `Submitter`.

Your third attempt: you now have a database or table diagram and no longer an entity-relationship diagram - in other words, you switched from a conceptual to a physical model.

- Foreign key constraints in table diagrams are directed, hence you can't use many-to-many connections between them.
- Your `Feedback` table requires a `Question ID`, meaning you have to insert each new question into the pre-existing list mentioned in point 3. Is that what the assignment intended?
- What is the primary key of the Feedback table?  Is it a composite of `Question ID` and `Recipient ID`?  However, `Feedback Assignment` seems to refer to a surrogate ID which doesn't exist.
- What is the primary key of the `Feedback Assignment` table?  Is it a composite of `Feedback ID` and `Employee ID`?  That's what `Feedback Results` refers to, meaning the surrogate ID is unnecessary.
- In `Feedback Results` the surrogate key `Results ID` seems redundant since AFAICT the combination of `Feedback ID` and `Employee ID` uniquely identifies each row.
- You still have an `Avg Table` which I believe is unnecessary since averages can be easily calculated with a query.
- In `Avg Table` you indicate the `Average Score` as a foreign key.  I don't see how this can work.  Shouldn't it use the `Feedback ID` instead as a foreign and primary key?
- Your `Views` constraint doesn't seem to correspond to any columns and is unnecessary IMO.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Edited the diagram

Comment: Could you review it now, I think I addressed all the issues